# Didn't Hear from HR after Selected in Interview

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, human-resources, india, hiring

I was selected for a particular post in a investment banking company. We had 3 interviews, 2 being technical and 1 being HR. They didn't say I was selected but only told that they are positive about my profile. HR asked for the details such as payslips of the current company I am working for and the offer letter of the current company, the same was sent of the Nov 2nd being same day.

All these steps took 3 days after the Nov 2nd 2020 and I haven't heard from them. Unfortunately I dont have there telephone number. Should I wait or start looking for other opportunities. PS: The current pay is too less for my qualificationand my expectation and is within their budget and market requirement.

Comment: In the title it says _"..after Selected in Interview"_ and in the question you state _" They didn't said I was selected but only told that they are positive about my profile.."_ Can you clarify?

Comment: "Grand son of J.P Morgan" - Be sure this was not a scam.

Comment: There are two HR, One who scheduled Interview and another who took Interview. The Person who took HR Interview told she is Positive about my profile. The One who scheduled Interview said Selected

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Google it you will get to know about the company.

Comment: @SagarSag _"Google it you will get to know about the company"_ So where is the issue? Get their phone number or e-mail and follow up on your application..

Comment: The company might be legit, the job offer and the interview might be a scam. Being in India, this is not unheard of.

Answer (score 5):

First off

> Should I wait or start looking for other opportunities

You should never have stopped. A job search doesn't end until both parties (you and the company) signed a legally binding contract. It is in your interest to pursue multiple job opportunities, so that you maximize your chances of getting a job.

> All these steps took 3 days after the Nov 2nd 2020 and I haven't heard from them

So (if I understand you correctly) it's been 7 days at the time of writing this and you haven't heard anything. In my book that's an adequate amount of time to wait before taking action. Reach out to them, preferably over email. Write a short email inquiring about the status of your application, something along the lines of

> Hi *HR persons name*,
>
> Thank you for taking the time to interview me on *interview date*, I enjoyed learning more about the *job title* position and wanted to follow up to see if any progress has been made in terms of a decision.
>
> Kind Regards
> Sagar sag

Feel free to elaborate on how you think the position would be a good match for you, but keep it succinct. If you already had contact with the person who interviewed you via email, I recommend you reply to the most recent one (the email in which you were invited).

P.S I recommend email communication over calling them, as the HR person can read and respond at their leisure, while a phone may come across as pushy and you demanding an update rather than asking for one.

Answer (score 2):

You ask if you should keep searching. As a general rule, until you have an official offer with your and their autograph under it, yes, you should keep searching.

Even if they get back to you tomorrow, their offer might simply not be good enough. Or it might be good enough, but only because you didn't get an even better offer due to not searching further.

Comment: Is it possible for them to reject after obtaining details from me, I always wanted to work in the investment banking industry

Comment: Of course they can reject you. You don't have a signed offer, they have no obligation to hire you.

Comment: erik thanks again for the help with the deletion!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a new job, then you don't stop looking until the offer letter is signed and returned and all preconditions have been met. Some people continue looking until the day before they start just in case they lose the contract, the boss quits, or the economy craters.

It doesn't matter how positive they seem, or how excited they are, or how much information they ask you to send. They may be telling 5 other people the same thing.

Don't focus on terms like "Selected" or "positive profile" they are designed to keep maybes from dropping out until the company knows which ones they are interested in.

We have a lot of questions on this site about people who were told the offer letter was coming today, and then never heard from the company. There are questions about people who were given a verbal offer and then never received a written offer.

There are also example of people who receive an offer letter weeks later, because the first or even the 2nd choice of the company rejected the offer.

So keep looking. Also reach out to the contacts at the other company and see what the status is. And while you wait their response apply to a few more places, and accept a few more interviews.

Answer (score 0):

I only saw one question in the whole post

> Should I wait or start looking for other opportunities.

The answer to that one is simple and universal:

***You should keep looking for other opportunities until you have a written offer in hand that's fully negotiated and that you are ready to sign.***